# IP getting access even after blocking

Tags: server, ufw, fail2ban

```
78.128.113.62 - - [04/Jan/2020:19:59:33 +0530] "GET /efk-dashboard HTTP/1.1" 404 66914 "-" "python-requests/2.13.0"
```

There are multiple access records like this even after I have run the commands

```bsh
ufw deny from 78.128.113.58/24 to any  # for ufw
ip route add unreachable 78.128.113    # for fail2ban
```

I also restarted the fail2ban service after adding the ip.

How to fix this issue? I run out of ideas.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

UFW rules are checked in sequence. The first rule that matches source and destination applies and remaining rules are ignored.

When you use a plain `ufw deny` command, the rule is added after the others (use `ufw status` to list the rules in order). If the source address matches an `allow` or `limit` line above your `deny` (and there is likely one), that allow/limit line applies and your rule is not checked.

To make sure your rule appears first, do:

```
ufw insert 1 deny from 78.128.113.58/24 to any
```

Answer (score 12):

The previous answer address why the `ufw` command didn't have an effect. However it does not explain why the `ip route` command had no effect.

The reason it had no effect for you is that `78.128.113` is being interpreted as `78.128.113.0/32`. Thus you are blocking only a single IP address which is not the one you are receiving traffic from. If you wanted to block the entire /24 IP range, you could use:

```
ip route add unreachable 78.128.113.0/24
```

It's important to notice that the `ip` command will only block the return traffic not the incoming traffic. That means incoming traffic from that IP range may still consume some resources on your host by creating half-open TCP connections or sending packets to stateless services (usually UDP based).

For those reasons a firewall rule such as those created with `ufw` will likely work better for your particular use case than an `ip route` command.